# How to add css style beside the bootstrap styles

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new in css and html
I added some bootstrap styles to my elements in HTML
as you know when you add bootstrap style to an element, the class would be taken . so I can not add my own css style to it .
is there anyway to fix this ??
is adding the ID to element the only way ?
Thanks  lot .

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you need to add a style to a class already handled in the bootstrap, you can use !important:

#idtag{
 color: red !important;
}

Comment: you can use any of the selector which css support regardless of you are using bootstrap or any other framework

Comment: The `class` attribute can hold multiple space-separated classes. Add your own custom classes beside any bootstrap classes.

Comment: Overriding with !important is hard to manage as your application grows....but reproducing the bootstrap selectors in a separate css file loaded after bootstrap is a good process.  This article breaks it down nicely https://www.bootstrapdash.com/bootstrap-css-styles/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the bootstrap elements have their own customization, such as changing from `bg-light` to `bg-dark`.
But if you need to change something you can simply assign a new class and make the necessary changes 
Example:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mystyle">Primary</button>
```

```css
.mystyle
{
    background-color: white;
}
```

If your styling doesn't apply just add `!important` to take priority over boostrap:

```css
.mystyle
{
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new CSS file and Add your own css file in your head tag!
and then write your own CSS on that file.
If some css are not overriding then, Used !important in the last

```css
body {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

```html
    <!--Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- Your CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="your-file-css.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First things if you want to override the default bootstrap you can do it by over-riding the default behavior as mention in bootstrap documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/ and for that you need sass to be install in your project folder too and if you are using simple CDN to use bootstrap then just add !important tag to your css i.e

```
    .btn-primary {
          background-color: red !important;
       }
```

Make sure the Bootstrap CDN come first and then your custom css file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `!important` rule to give highest priority to the property you described.

Example:

```css
#myid {
  background-color: blue;
}

.myclass {
  background-color: gray;
}

p {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```